# How to escape backslash in rangeprefix?

Tags: listings

I want to escape backslash to be used as a `rangeprefix` as follows. The current MWE does not work as expected because it still imports all codes rather than the codes sandwiched by `document` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xxx.xxx}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangeprefix=\textbackslash,
    rangesuffix=\{document\},   
    linerange=begin-end,
}   

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{xxx.xxx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had to give the `linerange` as `[]` argument to `\lstinputlisting` to get any effect. Unfortunately `\backslash`, `\textbackslash` and `\@backslashchar` all give “! Improper alphabetic constant.” then. I guess just leaving away `rangesuffix` works in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing from the listings manual:

> Keywords We begin with keyword building keys. Note: If you want to
>   **enter \,** {, }, %, # or & as (part of ) an argument to the keywords
>   below, you must do it with a preceding backslash!

To be fair, this is not in the section about `linerange`. There it only says

> Note that TEX’s special characters like the curly braces, the space,
>   the percent sign, and such must be escaped with a backslash.

But in deed you can use `\\` for an escaped backslash:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xxx.xxx}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangeprefix=\\,
    rangesuffix=\{document\},   
}   

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[linerange=begin-end]{xxx.xxx}
\end{document}
```

Oh and just a suggestion, the following is probably a little more flexible:

```
\lstset
{
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangebeginprefix=\\begin\{,
    rangeendprefix=\\end\{,
    rangesuffix=\},   
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[linerange=document-document]{xxx.xxx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\\`` is not the escaped version of ``\`` but a new line macro.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: In general that is true, but the way `lstset` is handling its arguments, `\\ ` is indeed an escaped backslash. I tried it and it works. If I remove the backslash in front of `begin` in the source code, the listing will be empty.

Comment: Can we move `linerange` to be a global option such that no need to repeat it again and again for each `\lstinputlisting` call?

Comment: @HiggsBoson: No, `listings` manual says “linerange can be used on individual listings only.”. But you could do `\def\mylst{\lstinputlisting[linerange=begin-end]}`.